# Stored procedure outputting duplicate records with multiple inner joins

Tags: sql-server

I am creating a stored procedure and would like to inner join between 4 different tables. The tables are names:

```
Category, SubCategory, Project, VisUser
```

`SubCategory` depends on `Category` and `VisUser` while `Project` depends on `SubCategory`.

When I run my stored procedure with the 3 inner joins, it returns the correct information - just duplicated 3 times.

I tried using distinct in the beginning and it does work to filter the records correctly however it may still run slow when running with a large amount of data with it outputting 3x the records.

Stored procedure:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS GetAllProjects
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllProjects
    (@UserId INT)
AS
BEGIN 
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        proj.ProjectName, proj.ProjectDescription, sub.SubCategoryName
    FROM 
        SubCategory AS sub
    INNER JOIN 
        VisUser AS vis ON @UserId = sub.UserId
    INNER JOIN 
        Category AS cat ON cat.CategoryId = sub.CategoryId
    INNER JOIN 
        Project AS proj ON proj.SubCategoryId = sub.SubCategoryId
END
```

What part am I doing wrong here? I have a feeling it is because I am using 'sub' 3x in the inner joins. Is there a better approach for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INNER JOIN VisUser AS vis ON @UserId = sub.UserId
```

Will join on all `VisUsers` because you don't reference the table in the join condition.

As you don't actually use the `VisUsers` table just remove it as follows:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT proj.ProjectName, proj.ProjectDescription, sub.SubCategoryName
FROM SubCategory AS sub
INNER JOIN Category AS cat ON cat.CategoryId = sub.CategoryId
INNER JOIN Project AS proj ON proj.SubCategoryId = sub.SubCategoryId
WHERE sub.UserId = @UserId;
```

And if you do need the VisUsers table you can join on like this:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT proj.ProjectName, proj.ProjectDescription, sub.SubCategoryName
FROM SubCategory AS sub
INNER JOIN VisUser AS vis ON vis.UserId = sub.UserId
INNER JOIN Category AS cat ON cat.CategoryId = sub.CategoryId
INNER JOIN Project AS proj ON proj.SubCategoryId = sub.SubCategoryId
WHERE sub.UserId = @UserId;
```